# Phabricator hosted Git repository setup issues

Tags: git, ssh, phabricator

Okay so I am having trouble setting up Git repository hosting on a Phabricator LEMP stack running on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server.

I followed the Diffusion hosting repository guide and I can add new hosted repository and it processes all successfully with finding the git library files and setting up the repository.

Now I have phd user **www-data**, entire Phabricator directory owned by **www-data**, and /var/repo where the hosted git repositories are owned by **www-data**.

I also have diffusion ssh-user as **vcs-user**.

**In /etc/passwd I have:**

> vcs-user:x:110:65534::/home/vcs-user:/bin/bash

**In /etc/sudoers I have:**

> vcs-user ALL=(www-data) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack, /usr/bin/git-receive-pack

**In /etc/shadow I have:**

> vcs-user:NP:16779:0:99999:7:::

I have the main login to the server on port 222.  I then run another instance of sshd on port 22 using the Phabricator hooks file to run for git ssh clone/pull/push operations.

**When I try and clone I get this error:**

```
C:\git clone ssh://vcs-user@xxx.xxx.xxx/diffusion/repo/project.git

Cloning into 'V4'...

ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.184 port 22: Connection refused

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**When I try and run from within the ssh connection an ssh query of the second instance I get:**

```
~$ echo {} | ssh -p 22 vcs-user@localhost conduit conduit.ping

Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

**The output of running the sshd instance in 3 level debug mode:**

```
~$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -d -d -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config.phabricator
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 322
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 50180 on 127.0.0.1 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 2278
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 107:65534 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 107/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-
hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
[preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@open
ssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndae
l-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@open
ssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndae
l-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-5
12,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-5
12,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-
hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
[preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-
nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.c
om,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,s
sh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@open
ssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndae
l-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@open
ssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndae
l-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-5
12,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@opens
sh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-5
12,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug1: kex: client-server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug1: kex: server-client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x7f7e96ac4700(101)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug2: kex_derive_keys [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user vcs-user service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 127.0.0.1.
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 322
debug3: auth_shadow_acctexpired: today 16782 sp_expire -1 days left -16783
debug3: account expiration disabled
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for vcs-user [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug1: userauth-request for user vcs-user service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=vcs-user devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 2278
```

Comment: In the line `C:\git clone ssh://vcs-user@xxx.xxx.xxx/diffusion/repo/project.git` I only miss the callsign. But this seems to be too easy to fix your issue. Just an idea.

Comment: So yea just to keep my project anonymous repo and project are keywords replaced by like the actual project I am working on.  Furthermore,  it seems to be failing at authenticating the vcs-user I setup which makes no since.  I am wondering if making it www-data instead of vcs-user since the /var/repo directory hosting the git repos is owned by www-data but the vcs-user has the same permissions in sudoers file as www-data so I don't understand.

Comment: We have similar setup. One user to connect to phabricators ssh port and another one to run phabricator. The important thing is, that the ssh user can only be authenticated by public key. For that you need to upload your public key to the phabricator UI to a dedicated user. Public keys uploaded before to .ssh/ or password authentication won't work any longer.